# How to get prev textarea element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, events

I want to get a text from a textarea after clicking on button that is next to the textarea.

The problem is that I will have many textareas and every button must returns the text of the textarea that corresponds to it.

This is my code

```js
function btnmodif(){

 var mod = $(this).prev().val();
 
 alert(mod);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list-item-edit">
   <textarea class="list_input">eggs</textarea>    
    <button class="btn btn-modify-item" onClick="btnmodif()">get text</button>
     
    </div>

<div class="list-item-edit">
   <textarea class="list_input">water</textarea>    
    <button class="btn btn-modify-item" onClick="btnmodif()">get text</button>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: prev() should work: https://api.jquery.com/prev/ and, you shouldn't use inline event handlers, its easier to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/ttpvb5yb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass `object` clicked to `btnmodif` function.

```
<button class="btn btn-modify-item" onClick="btnmodif(this)">get text</button>
```

JS

```
function btnmodif(button){
    var mod = $(button).prev().val();
    alert(mod);
};
```

Also, you should use `.prev` function.

Read more about `.prev()` function, [here](https://api.jquery.com/prev/).

```js
function btnmodif(button){
 var mod = $(button).prev().val();
 alert(mod);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list-item-edit">
   <textarea class="list_input">eggs</textarea>    
    <button class="btn btn-modify-item" onClick="btnmodif(this)">get text</button>
     
</div>

<div class="list-item-edit">
   <textarea class="list_input">water</textarea>    
    <button class="btn btn-modify-item" onClick="btnmodif(this)">get text</button>
     
</div>
```

Comment: What benefit does `closest` have over `prev` assuming the element is always the previous element?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to pass the clicked element as context to the function:

```
onClick="btnmodif(this)"
```

...

```
function btnmodif(button){
```

Second, if the HTML structure will remain the same (i.e. the textarea is always going to be the element immediately before the button), then you can use `prev()`

```
var mod = $(button).prev('textarea').val();
```

https://api.jquery.com/prev/

If that structure isn't guaranteed to be maintained, then `.siblings()` gives you a bit more flexibility, as it searches through all the elements at the same hierarchical level in the DOM to find what you want:

```
var mod = $(button).siblings('textarea').val();
```

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: While totally accurate information, this doesn't solve the problem of OP's `this` context being `window` and not the `button` as OP expected it to be.

Comment: @Fran well spotted. Looks like the accepted answer has got that covered, but I'll add it in here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what are you looking for.

- Add `this` as parameter to your button.onclick

Thanks to jQuery:

- Using `$(element).parent()`, you get your div element.
- Using `$(element).parent().find('.list_input')`, you get your textarea element.
- Using `$(element).parent().find('.list_input').text()` gives you the value of the textarea "related to" the clicked button.

```js
function btnmodif(element){
    var result = $(element).parent().find('.list_input').text();
    alert(result);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list-item-edit">
   <textarea class="list_input">eggs</textarea>    
    <button class="btn btn-modify-item" onClick="btnmodif(this)">get text</button>
     
    </div>

<div class="list-item-edit">
   <textarea class="list_input">water</textarea>    
    <button class="btn btn-modify-item" onClick="btnmodif(this)">get text</button>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: If you pass the button reference into the function `prev()` works just fine. Using `parent().find()` when you have a handle on the button is redundant DOM iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `this` from the inline handler specification:

https://jsfiddle.net/3mvod6ux/

Use [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) with a selector to get the `textarea`'s value that belong to the same block of the button clicked.

```
function btnmodif(button){
    var mod = $(button).siblings("textarea").val();
    alert(mod);
};
```

Comment: Why do additional DOM iterations with `siblings`, searching for multiple siblings when OPs original code, using `prev` works and just fetches the previous element?

Comment: @Fran actually the original code used "find", which wouldn't work. OP only changed it to prev after someone suggested it in the comments - see the edit history!

Comment: @fran He did not use prev at first. He used find.

Comment: @james_bond - I see. Fair point. Is there still a benefit using `siblings` over `prev` then though?

Comment: @fran prev takes into account the order of the element in the dom, if for some reason he swaps the order of the button and the textarea the code with prev won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this task .
Instead to use HTML event attribute this is better approach.

```
var btnModifyItem = $('.btn-modify-item');

btnModifyItem.click(function(){
    var mod = $(this).prev().val();
    alert(mod);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This way you can get the parent of `button` (and `textarea`) and then can get the text from child `textarea`:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
            console.log(($(this).parent().find("textarea").text()));
        });
```

Comment: If you use `on` the `this` context is always the button and `prev()` works fine. Using `parent().find()` when you have a handle on the button is redundant DOM iteration.

Comment: Downvoted! Really for this? Doesn't it answers his query? Was he/she talking about performance and redundant code?

Comment: when you hover over the downvote button it says "This answer is not useful" my personal opinion is that encouraging redundant DOM iterations is not useful. Even `siblings` or `closest` is better. `parent()` iterates through the complete DOM tree all the way to the document root before returning with the match making this the longest possible route to the previous element.

Comment: IMO the usefulness definition is 'OP want to get the text from the textarea next to the button'. Anyways you got rights!